# unable to launch sencha architect - internet connection error

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-architect, sencha-cmd

I am about to work on ExtJs and downloaded Sencha Architect to build some application, but this is showing me the error that Unable to establish internet connection.[image]

I don't know why this is giving this..did anyone face this issue..? Pls help me

Comment: I have faced this issue one. Simply I didn't have internet connection. Are you sure you are connected and no firewall is blocking the SA?

Answer (score 0):

1) Check firewall.

2) Check your proxy settings. Having a proxy in place will cause this to happen.

3) Try it on a different network.

4) Lastly check if indeed you dont have a connection.